# Pylint doesn't recognize numpy.log()

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pylint

I re-downloaded Visual Studio Code and made sure pylint is up to date.

```
np.log(array)
```

Has a red underline and is flagged as an error. Here is the error message that is displayed when I hover over the line:

> E1101:Module 'numpy' has no 'log' member; maybe 'long'?

This doesn't make sense because np definitely has the method log and the code runs fine without error. It doesn't interfere with the code, but it is annoying to look at and doesn't make sense.

Comment: Do you have a file named numpy.py in that directory? (assuming you used import numpy as np)

Comment: It could be that the internal lookup cache is expired. Not sure how its done in Visual Studio, but see if there is an option to regenerate the cache.